# WC Vendors - Custom Taxonomy Checklist Not Saving on Front-End

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, wcvendors

I'm using WC Vendors and have output the taxonomy named "location" on the products using wp_term_checklist per their suggestion. I've got it saving to the product, but it's not saving the checkbox selection on the front-end.
This is the code I've added to the product-edit.php template

```
$args = array(
        'descendants_and_self'  => 0,
        'selected_cats'         => false,
        'popular_cats'          => false,
        'walker'                => null,
        'taxonomy'              => 'location',

        'checked_ontop'         => false
    );
    wp_terms_checklist( $my_postid, $args );
    
    $post_to_edit = array(
        'ID'           => $my_postid,
        'tax_input'    =>  array( 'location' => array($_POST['tax_input']['location']) )
    );
    
    $pid = wp_update_post($post_to_edit);
    
    if ( isset($_POST['tax_input']['location']) && is_array( $_POST['tax_input']['location'] ) ) { 
        $location = array_map( 'intval', $_POST['tax_input']['location'] ); 
        $location = array_unique( $location ); 
        wp_set_post_terms($pid, $location, 'location'); 
    }
```

This is their code where they use a multi-select, but we need checkboxes:
https://gist.github.com/digitalchild/128033d2d41f682acd4387b595d4f607

Answer (score 0):

We have a custom terms checklist called wcv_terms_checklist() in our form helper. It didn't support custom taxonomies but I have modified it to support that now. You can use the following code from v1.7.10 and above to get working custom terms checklists on our front end.

```
// Output the location checklist 
function form_location( $object_id ) { 
    
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'location',
    );

    $field = array(
        'id'    => 'product_loc_list',
        'label' => __( 'Location', 'wcvendors-pro' ),
        'class' => 'product_cat_checklist',
    );

    WCVendors_Pro_Form_Helper::wcv_terms_checklist( $object_id, $args, $field );

} 
add_action( 'wcv_after_product_details', 'form_location' );

// Save the terms 
function save_location( $post_id ){ 
    if ( isset(  $_POST[ 'location' ] ) && is_array( $_POST[ 'location' ] ) ) { 
        $location = array_map( 'intval', $_POST[ 'location' ] ); 
        $location = array_unique( $location ); 
        wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $location, 'location' ); 
    } 
} 
add_action( 'wcv_save_product', 'save_location' );
```

Gist available here - https://gist.github.com/digitalchild/09e15649425845fef0b8d3af75c79dd1